# Looking a method to access the total unread messages in the primary tab

Tags: javascript, gmail

I have used the `"in:unread category:primary"` query in Gmail and it displays the information i am looking for, along with the total as a number (for example "1-8 of 8"). I have used the following code to produce the same effect.

```
var monitor = "unread ";
var primAry = "primary";
var search = "in:monitor" + "category:" + primAry;
var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 5);
```

To read each message I use the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
}
```

I am aware of `getInboxUnreadCount()` and `getPriorityInboxUnreadCount()` methods.

Is there a method to assign to a variable the total number of unread emails 
in the primary tab, as Gmail does (eg "1-8 of 8")?

Comment: Have found that the URL

Comment: Have found that the URL https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom can display the total unread emails but still unable to find a method on how  to find, unread emails in the primary folder other than using  "in:unread category:primary" direct into gmail search while on line. I am hoping to find a way to do this via JavaScript so as to use it in a Google sheet script any pointers ? would it be some thing like subtract getPriorityInboxUnreadCount() from getInboxUnreadCount() ?

Comment: On method to solve the problem is to repeat the read                       'threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 5);'                                             read until     'threads == 0'                                                                       due to certain limitations & the quantity of emails you may have,           a time event may be needed for each read